# Corpus of Taboo card game?

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, resource-request, language-games

Has anyone constructed a corpus of people playing the card game Taboo, in a purely text-based setting, like a computer chat, rather than face-to-face with audio or video? The closest I've found are papers like

- [Morphological Annotation of a Corpus with a Collaborative Multiplayer Game](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.613.2779&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which investigates Turkish morphology
- [Modelling Word Associations with Word Embeddings for a Guesser Agent in the Taboo City Challenge Competition](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/r.fernandezrovira/papers/2017/dankers-etal-essence2017.pdf), which is limited to city names
- [Semantic Taboo–A Serious Game for Vocabulary Acquisition](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01618507/document)
- [Towards Automatic Identification of Effective Clues for Team Word-Guessing Games](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/L16-1435.pdf), which has a similar goal but does not have "taboo" or "off-limit" words in the clues

Any help would be greatly appreciated.